# Python Sqlite and Excel output with headers and Row ID

Tags: python, excel, sqlite, header, export

Please help to find correct solution from "simple to customize in future" point of view.
I have SQLite table and very big select. After this select I got 5 column and any rows.
I want to export this data to Special Excel file and Special Sheet. But not just export, I want add row = 0 with Headers of table. For example: header = [('Place', 'Players', 'Score', 'Delta', 'Game')].
For each row from SQLite I need add index to Place column from 1 to XXX.
Headers should be simple configure in future.

I try to directly import data from sqlite to excel, but in this case header not added. (here Players_Last_Day_Stat - sql select)
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
workbook = Workbook('Total_Stat.xlsx')

```
conn = create_connection()
c=conn.cursor()

worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Last-Day')
mysel=c.execute(Players_Last_Day_Stat)
for i, row in enumerate(mysel):
    for j, value in enumerate(row):
        if isinstance(value, float):
            value = int(value)
        worksheet.write(i, j, value)
```

But result like this
[image]

I expect this result finally:
[image]

Also, hot to change some cell bolt from python?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. To make an index for your table, you can use [`worksheet.write_column`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html). Here is what you can do to implement that (based on your code) and to shift the table (*one column to the right and one row below*) :

```
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

workbook = Workbook('Total_Stat.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Last-Day')

conn = create_connection()
c = conn.cursor()
mysel = c.execute(Players_Last_Day_Stat)

header = ['Place', 'Players', 'Score', 'Delta', 'Game']
for idx, col in enumerate(header):
    worksheet.write(0, idx, col) # <- write the column name one time in a row

#this was untouched
for i, row in enumerate(mysel):
    for j, value in enumerate(row):
        if isinstance(value, float):
            value = int(value)
        worksheet.write(i+1, j+1, value)

worksheet.write_column(1, 0, [i for i in range(1, len(c.execute(Players_Total_Stat).fetchall()) + 1)]) # make an index

#here, we make both 1st column/row bold
bold_fmt = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
worksheet.set_row(0, None, bold_fmt)
worksheet.set_column(0, 0, None, bold_fmt)
```

Comment: Thank you. But mysel it's execute script result with type "Cursor", what don't have len        worksheet.write_column(1, 0, [i for i in range(1, len(mysel) + 1)])  # make an index
TypeError: object of type 'sqlite3.Cursor' has no len()

Comment: I try this ( len(mysel.fetchall()) ) . But result 0 :(

Comment: Let’s try enumerate. I updated my answer, can you check it out ?

Comment: Finally I made it like this worksheet.write_column(1, 0, [i for i in range(1, len(c.execute(Players_Total_Stat).fetchall()) + 1)])  # make an index

Comment: Nice, good to know. I will add it to the answer then ;)

Comment: enumerate - not help.. Same like fetchall. Only after I executer SELECT again I can get row count. Looks like cursor data lost. I don't know root cause, by logic should work fetchall and enumerate. But in any case I done this task with your help. Thank you.